# Chrome 72: Google Cast Api unavailable in update on android

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

The cast api seems to be unavailable since I updated to Chrome 72 on android. I tested on several devices, everything worked fine prior to the update.
The cast api is inaccessible on my web app but also on youtube !! (web version)

Has it been deprecated or is this a bug?
Any information would help thanks.

Tested in chrome 72 on oneplus 6t as well as samsung a8 (working prior update, and no-longer post update).

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide more details about the failure?

Deprecation is not noted in the [Chrome 72 deprecations](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/12/chrome-72-deps-rems). Notably, the presentation API appears to have been [restricted to secure (HTTPS) contexts](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1306336) in Chrome 72, but YouTube is HTTPS...

Comment: Thabk you for your message, I updated the question and specified the devices used for testing. I had already had a look at the chrome deprecations and didn't seem to find anything about google cast. Anyways filed a bug report here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=928325&q=label%3ANeeds-triage-Mobile&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified